# Get Recent and Custom posts from same wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I am using this code from which I am able to get 3 recent posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'property', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'DESC'));
```

and I am using this code to get 3 custom posts with the post__in method.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'property', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post__in' => array( 10244, 7177, 8262)));
```

How can I combine them to get the 3 recent and 3 custom posts from one loop?

Any Help Appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by merging their posts into one query.
f.e.

```
$merged_query = new WP_Query();
$merged_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
```

Example:

```
<?php 
    $merged_query = new WP_Query();
    $merged_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
    while ( $merged_query->have_posts() ) : $merged_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how i will get 3 recent and 3 custom posts from the merge array? Could you please show me the code?